# Find the area and the volume of the tetrahedron

Tags: vector, geometry, analytical

So given ABCD, A(0,0,0) B(1,1,0) , C(1,-1,1) ,D, (3,0,1)
 I need to find the volume of the tetrahedron now I know that the volume of the tetrahedron  = 1/6 detA 
But the determinat of this matrix  is 0 so that's it I have the volume  = 0 or I didn't calculate it right

Answer (score 0):

The determinant is

```
1*(-1)*1 + 1*1*3 - 1*1*1 = -1 + 3 - 1 = 1
```

I used the Sarrus Rule to calculate it. The other terms are zero.

So yes, you didn't calculate it right.

Comment: Now I don't have the same answer I used the scalar product and the answer is 1/6 and according to your answer is -1/6!

Comment: now I have different answers by determinats according to your answer it's -1/6 , and by the scalar product 1/6!

Comment: @TawTaw: The determinant I calculated is 1, so the volume is 1/6. Aside from that, a volume can not be negative.